# How to insert a stored procedure in to Exixting database?

Tags: mysql

I have a database created as ready with some stored procedures. Now i want to add another stored procedure(external) into my existing database using MySql or SqlYog. Can anybody Help me ??

Answer (score 0):

Use MySQL work bench to script the stored procedure on the database instance you would like to add the stored procedure.

See this link: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/getting-started-with-mysql-stored-procedures.aspx

It will guide you through the process.

Comment: Awesome! Can you mark this answer as correct answer please. Thanks :)